# how to store elasticsearch query result to new index directly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three questions.

First, I wonder if I can save the mtermvectors query results back to a new index using a single query.

Second, If first question is okay, I wonder if I can change the current format to the nested data type when saving the result.

Last, I wonder if I can do aggregation at the same time.
Is it possible?

Now, my code is here.

```
<pre>
GET /_mtermvectors?pretty=true 
{   
  "docs":[
  {   "_index": "test",    
    "_type": "type1",    
    "_id": "2",    
    "fields":["contents"],    
    "offsets":false,    
    "payloads":false,    
    "positions":false,    
    "term_statistics": true,
    "field_statistics":true,   
    "filter":{
    "min_term_freq":1,
    "max_doc_freq": 3
}   },   
 {   "_index": "test",    
   "_type": "type1",    
   "_id": "1",    
   "fields":["contents"],    
   "offsets":false,    
   "payloads":false,    
   "positions":false,    
   "term_statistics": true,
   "field_statistics":true,  
   "filter":{
  "min_term_freq":1,
  "max_doc_freq": 3
}   
} ] }


PUT /new_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "word": {
    "properties": {
       "termsarray": {
         "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
         "form": { 
           "type":"text",
           "fielddata": true
    }
        }
      }
   }
   }
}
```

}

```
GET new_index/_search
{
 "aggs" : {
    "termsarray" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "termsarray"
        },
       "aggs" : {
    "word" : {
       "terms" : { 
         "field" : "termsarray.form",
          "order" : { "sum_score" : "desc" }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "sum_score" : { "sum" : { "field" : "termsarray.score" }}
        }
    }
 }
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Hey, asking three questions at once with a poorly formatted piece of code is not a good way to get answers. Questions on SO shall answer one thing, so when people come from Google (like me now), get just the right answer. I'd suggest leaving just the basic question and asking the others in new questions if still actual for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this post on ES forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-there-a-standard-way-to-store-result-of-query-into-index/110650/2), it is not possible to store query result directly back to ES as a new index. You have to fetch the data to client and push them into the new index yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using LogStash you can store elasticsearch query result into a new or existing index:

You have to combine elasticsearch input

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html

And elastic search output

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method to search and store is to use `elasticdump` with the parameter `--searchBody`.

Or, if you got your search results from e.g. Kibana like this:

```
GET your-index/_search?pretty=false&filter_path=**._source&size=1000
```

then copy-paste the output to a JSON file and:

```
jq -c '.hits.hits[]' your-results.json | \
    elasticdump --input=$ --output="http://localhost:9200/your-new-index" --limit=1000
```

P.S. if you don't have `jq`, use `sed` instead:

```
sed -e 's/^{"hits":{"hits":\[//' -e 's/\]}}$//' -e 's/},{"_source":{/}\n{"_source":{/g'
```